# How do you check for a valid session in Struts 2 jsp?

Tags: session, struts

I have an include jsp on all my pages which includes js files, css files, etc.  This include jsp also refers to the session with "".

On the last page of my application, the action does a session.invalidate on the HttpSession object.

So when the last the last page of my application appears and runs the "", I get the following error since the session is invalidated

> 2011-10-19 10:30:59,134 WARN com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack - Caught an exception while evaluating expression '#session.user.isWhatever()' against value stack
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1062)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap.get(SessionMap.java:165)
>       at ognl.MapPropertyAccessor.getProperty(MapPropertyAccessor.java:76)

I have tried "#session neq null" to stop the error from appearing but that doesn't work.

Is there anyway/condition to use to stop this error?  How does one check if the session is valid in the jsp in Struts 2?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of a known session value--in your case, `#session.user`. You shouldn't have to do an explicit null check, IIRC (could be wrong). Depending on how things are actually working in your app, you can also check for [`isNew`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), although that seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

The session will "never" be null--unless explicitly directed otherwise, just hitting a JSP page will create one.